# Multilevel scrollable menu

Tags: html, css, menu, scrollable

I want to make a multilevel scrollable menu. How can I do it?
Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GodRevenge/jq1zrkwo/2/) I make for testing:

```
.nav ul {
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: block;
overflow: scroll;
max-height: 100px;
}
```

I have tried out to set the max-height, and add the overflow: scroll. But it doesnt display what I want. I want it to be eg: level 2 scrollable, meanwhile level 3, level 4 still stay side by side when i mouse over it.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Is this better ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jq1zrkwo/4/

just removed this :

```
max-height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: Yeah. remove that will work prefect. But I want to make it scrollable. example: i want to set level 2 to three column, after 3 column will be a scroll bar. In the same time, I want to make level 3 or 4 display correctly after I set the scrollbar.

Comment: Your "ul's" are INTO other ul's (this is normal) SO, when you will display them, there will always be a x-scrollbar... this is the main problem. The only way I see to fix that display problem is to manage it with "jquery/javascript"

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah, I think jquery or javascript is the only way. :)

Comment: define a class on the "2nd level dropdown elements". Then, on "hover" resize & place the "next visible dropdown" as wanted. If you are careful with "caller item" (* class li) : position & so on. That should do the trick ;) the jquery function .find() will find you the child element with selector (.find(".submenu")), event.target (in your function) will be the caller element...